# Cosa significa "commissariare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Recentemente è apparsa la [notizia dei manifesti contro il Papa affissi in alcune strade di Roma](http://roma.repubblica.it/cronaca/2017/02/04/foto/roma_manifesti_contro_papa_francesco_a_prati-157548599/1/), in cui si poteva leggere:

> hai **commissariato** Congregazioni

Non riesco a afferrare il senso del verbo "commissariare" in questa espressione. L'ho cercato in alcuni dizionari, tuttavia
mi sembra particolarmente difficile da capire. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

**Aggiornamento:**
Grazie a @DenisNardin, mi sono accorta che [questo articolo](http://m.ilgiornale.it/news/2016/12/22/commissariato-lordine-di-malta-il-papa-indaga-sulle-epurazioni/1345320/) fa anche uso del verbo "commissariare" in un contesto simile:

> **Commissariato** l'Ordine di Malta. Il Papa indaga sulle epurazioni

> Epurazione che non è piaciuta a Papa Francesco, tanto da spingerlo a **commissariare** i Cavalieri di Malta.

> Forse anche per questo Bergoglio ha deciso di **commissariarla** con la costituzione di "un gruppo di cinque autorevoli membri con l'incarico di raccogliere elementi atti ad informare compiutamente e in tempi brevi la Santa Sede in merito alla vicenda".

Per me va anche bene una spiegazione del significato di "commissariare" in questo contesto.

Comment: L'idea è quella di una ingerenza eccessiva  da parte di Papa Francesco riguardo alcuni enti religiosi o parareligiosi. Non so se tutti questi enti siano stati di fatto veramente commissariati, il messaggio di protesta vuole mettere in luce il potere (a loro dire indebito ed eccessivo) che il Papa sta esercitando.

Comment: in Italia 'commissariare' è frequentissimo, ciò perché è tutto commissariato. L'Italia stessa è commissariata ormai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dal [dizionario Hoepli](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/commissariare.php)

> **commissariare** [com-mis-sa-rià-re] (*commissàrio, -ri, commissàriano; commissariànte; commissariàto*)
>   v.tr.
>
> BUR Sostituire gli amministratori alla testa di organizzazioni politiche, imprese o enti periferici, con un commissario nominato dalla direzione centrale

Il manifesto si riferisce probabilmente a [questa notizia](http://www.ilgiornale.it/news/cronache/commissariato-lordine-malta-papa-indaga-sulle-epurazioni-1345320.html), in cui il papa è intervenuto in una vicenda "interna" all'ordine di Malta, nominando dei commissari straordinari, invece di lasciare che i Cavalieri lavassero i propri panni sporchi in casa. Come fa notare @DaG nei commenti, l'uso di *commissariamento* in questo caso non è proprio corretto, ma vuole far riferimento ad un ingerenza da parte dell'organo centrale su fatti locali.

Comment: Nella notizia sull'Ordine di Malta, però, quando si afferma che il Papa decise di "commissariare i Cavalieri di Malta", mi è sembrato capire che significasse che aveva inviato "un gruppo di cinque autorevoli membri con l'incarico di raccogliere elementi atti ad informare compiutamente e in tempi brevi la Santa Sede in merito alla vicenda". Non si parla di "sostituzione degli amministratori alla testa dell'organizzazione" da parte del Papa.

Comment: @Charo È possibile che il manifesto si riferisca ad un altro episodio. In ogni caso commissariare significa rimpiazzare gli amministratori di un organizzazione (in questo caso il Gran Maestro dell'ordine di Malta) con uno o più commissari di nomina diretta (in questo caso i "cinque autorevoli membri").

Comment: Non importa se il manifesto fa riferimento ad altri episodi: per me va anche bene una spiegazione sull'uso del verbo "commissariare" nell'articolo sull'Ordine di Malta. Voglio semplicemente capire il significato del verbo in questo tipo di contesti, non raccogliere informazioni su cosa succede al Vaticano.

Comment: Tuttavia nella notizia si afferma: "Nei giorni scorsi è trapelata la notizia delle dimissioni (forzate) del Gran Cancelliere Albrecht Freiherr von Boeselager il quale avrebbe chiuso gli occhi sulla distribuzione di preservativi negli ospedali dell'Ordine (SMOM) in Africa. Epurazione che non è piaciuta a Papa Francesco, tanto da spingerlo a commissariare i Cavalieri di Malta." Cioè, non è il Papa quello che forza la dimissione del Gran Cancelliere dell'Ordine di Malta. Anzi, si dice che tale epurazione non è piaciuta al Papa.

Comment: @Charo Il punto è che il papa è intervenuto in una vicenda "interna" all'ordine di Malta, nominando dei commissari straordinari, invece di lasciare che i Cavalieri si lavassero i propri panni sporchi in casa.

Comment: Penso che sia già chiaro dal resto, ma credo che tecnicamente nel caso dei cavalieri di Malta non si tratti di un vero e proprio commissariamento, ma viene chiamato così giornalisticamente, come quando si dice che viene “licenziato” un allenatore, si parla di un “divorzio” fra due soci, o altri usi lievemente impropri ma concisi ed espressivi.